# findItem() returns null for 1 of 3 menu items

Tags: android, android-menu

This is the XML document where I define my menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/search"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/locate"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_locate"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/locate"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/favorite"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_star"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/favorite"/>

</menu>
```

And here's where I assign the menu items to variables (`mainMenu` is a private variable that gets set in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`):

```
MenuItem favorite = mainMenu.findItem(R.id.favorite);       
MenuItem search = mainMenu.findItem(R.id.search);
MenuItem locate = mainMenu.findItem(R.id.locate);
```

This results in two of the variables being assigned identifiers, and one variable  being assigned `null`. In all cases, the null variable corresponds to the menu item *defined second in the XML file* (in this case, `locate`). If I move `locate` after `favorite` in the XML, `favorite` will be null. The order in which the three variables are assigned in Java doesn't matter.

I'm flummoxed. What am I missing?

Comment: If ZouZou's answer below does not help, we may need to see your onCreateOptionsMenu function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling the wrong menu resource. I don't see how that would have caused the problem, but I'm not complaining.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to cast your object  like :

```
MenuItem favorite = (MenuItem)mainMenu.findItem(R.id.favorite);
```

Nervetheless, if you want to perform actions on this items you can also override the method `onOptionsItemSelected`.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.search:
        // stuff
        break;
    case R.id.locate:
                   //stuff
         break;
    case R.id.favorite:
                   //stuff
         break;
   default:
        break; 
            }
    }
```